# Why do I get this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in Swift Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, ads

I'm trying to ad an Ad network called StartApps and 'Im following this guideline.(https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/iOS-Swift-InApp-Documentation#step3)

The problem is that I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

At

```
viewController.startAppAd!.showAd()
```

in my GameScene.swift. Why does this happen. Thanks!

```
 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

     var startAppAd: STAStartAppAd?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         startAppAd = STAStartAppAd()    
     }


     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        startAppAd!.loadAd()
     }



     //Im calling the function showsAds() in the GameScene.swift file

     class GameScene: SKScene {


         var viewController = GameViewController()

         override func didMoveToView() {
         }

         // interstitial ads randomnly appear after hero hits enemy
         func interstitialAdsRandom(){
              var randomAd = Int(arc4random() % 2)
              println(randomAd)
              if randomAd == 0 {
                  viewController.startAppAd!.showAd()
                  println("showad")      
              }         

         }   

      }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, just maybe. you want to declare where you get the error? ;)I guess `startAppAd!.loadAd()` but we can’t know for sure unless you add in where you get the error ;)

Comment: My bad.. this is where the error occured:                 viewController.startAppAd!.showAd()

Comment: try accessing the variable directly. use `startAppAd!.showAd()` instead of `viewController.startAppAd!.showAd()`

Comment: No that doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you are force-unwrapping the variable startAppAd. That is what force-unwrapping does.

If you change that exclamation point to a question mark, it will make it so that the method call is skipped if the optional contains nil.

```
startAppAd?.loadAd()
```

If you want to write the best code, you should use "if let" syntax, known as optional binding:

```
if let startAppAd = startAppAd
{
  startAppAd.loadAd()
}
else
{
  //startAppAd is nil. Handle that error case
}
```

Comment: How would I use this code with my interstitialAdsRandom() function? Thanks!

Comment: See if you can figure it out. If you can't get it to work, post the code that you tried as an edit at the bottom of your original question along with what's happening now. You won't learn very much if I just write your code for you. Besides, I bill people for writing their code for them. :)

Comment: I put the if let code in my GameViewController.swift and then I have to call it in my function interstitialAdsRandom()?

Comment: If you change `viewController.startAppAd!.showAd()` to `viewController.startAppAd?.showAd()` then the call will simply fail silently when startAppAd is nil. If you change your code to use `if let` syntax than you can write an else clause that does something different if the variable is nil.

Comment: You should read the section of the iBook "The Swift Programming Language" on Optionals. Read up on optional unwrapping, forced unwrapping, and optional binding. You're thrashing around in the dark and the docs are well written and pretty clear.